# Strange PHP errors on mPDF and PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7, mpdf

I'm using mPDF 7.0 to generate PDF files on web app hosted on Shared hosting account and it works fine. I tested it on other shared hosting account also works fine, but when I uploaded on VPS server I got some strange php errors in some of the mPDF library core files. PHP version on VPS is 7.0.10 (on shared hosting accounts is also tested with PHP 7.X versions and works fine). mbstring, gd, bcmath extensions are enabled in php.ini.

Here is example of the error:
On line with this code only `const SCALE = 72 / 25.4;` I got this error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in /vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php on line 58". Also I got errors on "**" operator, etc.

If somebody experienced similar problem and have some solution I would appreciate any help to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are running mPDF with an older PHP server? Can you dump `phpinfo();` in the PDF?

Comment: I tested on PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0.27 on shared hosting and it is working fine. VPS, where the errors occur, is running PHP 7.0.10.

Comment: You *think* you're running PHP 7 but you're not.

Comment: John Conde thank you for your comment, but according phpinfo() I think and it is running on PHP 7 `PHP Version 7.0.10`

Comment: @VasilGorgiev I seriously doubt that. See this issue https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/625, that could point you the right direction.